# Effect to a SSLEngine when calling init() of a shared SSLContext object again

Tags: java, ssl, sslengine, sslcontext, ultraesb

I have an implementation of reactor pattern in which I load the `SSLContext` when a `TransportListener` (Basically a listener listening on a given port for HTTPS connections.) is starting.

Then I call the same `init()` method again (through a **JMX** call to a listener's method)

```
sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
```

once I add or remove a certificate to/from the trust store. I have to reload the `SSLContext` in order to avoid any down time in the listener.

So this is the problem I'm currently facing.

Suppose a request come to the listener and an connection is established. If I reload the `SSLContext` object before the response is returned to the client, will that affect the connection's `SSLEngine` object's `wrap` process which encrypts the payload before sending?

**Note** : I have validated that the same `SSLContext` object is being passed to all the SSLEngines.The SSLContext object is passed to several other objects when the Listener is starting. For example, I have a connection pool to which I have to pass this SSLContext object. Therefore creating a new SSLContext object will completely break the existing connections is the connection pool. That is why i'm trying to use the same SSLContext object.

Comment: There was nothing preventing you from testing this for yourself *before* deciding it is what you 'have to' do. There is nothing stopping you from starting to use a *new* `SSLContext` whenever you load a new certificate: this will also avoid any downtime in the listener. You can't pass the same `SSLSession` to any `SSLEngines` at all, let alone to multiple ones. Do you mean `SSLContext`?

Comment: ...and you can modify the truststore without setting up a new context.

Comment: I have tested this for all other use cases. But I am unable to reproduce a scenario like what I have mentioned above (modify  the sslcontext before sending the response but after receiving the request). @eckes I do not have a problem with modifying the trust store. What I need is to reload the trust store at run time without restarting the `Listener`.

Comment: @EJP I can't really understand what you are saying. What i'm saying is, the SSLContext object is passed to several other objects when the `Listener` is starting. For example, I have a connection pool to which I have to pass this `SSLContext` object. Therefore creating a new `SSLContext` object will completely break the flow. That is why i'm trying to use the same SSLContext object.

Comment: You need to read your own post. What you *actually said* was, and I quote, 'the same `SSLSession` object is being passed to all the `SSLEngines`'. Please clarify. And 'therefore creating a new SSLContext object will completely break the existing connections [in] the connection pool' is just  a guess, not an established fact.

Comment: @EJP Sorry, i updated it. I'm passing the `SSLContext` object. Where I'm confused is, I do not have a way to verify whether the existing connections use the current `SSLContext` object when wrapping and unwrapping data?

Comment: They do if they have to engage in a re-handshake, as they have to access cipher suites, protocols, trusted certificates, private keys, etc. And I don't know what 'passing an `SSLContext` to an `SSLEngine`' means. `SSLEngines` are created *from* `SSLContexts.`

Comment: I dont see a reason the reinit with a new context. The trust manager is queried on each new connection, it immediatelly will pick up changes. You just need to use an provider which can actually be modified. It does of yourse not work for established sessions (unless you force a renegotiaion which is frowned upon anyway)

Comment: @eckes what do you mean by a provider?

Comment: An implementation providing the TrustManager interface which is mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think this through. If you have an established connection, it has already had a certificate exchange, successfully, so it has no need of new certificates, so no need of a new or reinitialized `SSLContext`, up to and including partial handshakes, e.g. to rekey the current session, or request a client certificate. It shouldn't use the SSLContext at all for anything short of a full handshake.

What you need to do is starting using a *new* `SSLContext` for all the *new* connections that are going to need the new certificate. You don't need to do anything to existing connections, by definition.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. i updated it. I'm passing the `SSLContext` object. What i want to know is, whether the existing socket connections, which use `SSLEngine` objects to wrap and unwrap get affected by changing the `SSLContext` object's trust managers. That is a problem only in a scenario where a request has received but the response is yet to be sent. Is there a possibility of incoming connection being unwrapped using a set of keys and response being wrapped using a separate set of keys which will break the communication is the above scenario?

Comment: The session keys are in the `SSLSession`, not the `SSLContext`, but I still don't see why you think you need to reinitialize the `SSLContext of an existing connection.

Comment: That means, `SSLEngine` only use `SSLContext` for the hand shake. Therefore afterwards, a change in the `SSLContext` do not affect the existing `SSLSession` or `SSLEngine` of a connection/socket if it is not a handshake. Am I correct?

Comment: As far as I can see that should be correct. If it's a partial handshake, e.g. to rekey the current session, or request a client certificate, it shouldn't use the `SSLContext` at all.

Comment: ok. Thanks for your help. Can you add that part also to the answer so that i can accept it as the answer :)